# How to sort number of numeric columns in one go

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

[image: input-output]

I have 350 columns. Below is a subset of all the data.

[image: Sample data in an Excel spreadsheet divided into rows for year and month and columned by district.]

I used "Sort Smallest to Largest" tool. It gives results only for one column. If not, it can sort the first column and other columns will change according to the first one. But I want to sort all columns A-Z separately.

I want to sort the data by district.

Comment: I would like to suggest, share some sample data and expected output, will help us to fix the issue!

Comment: Thank you for your attention. first i am sorry for the spelling mistake of sort. i have added screenshot of the data set.

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table? A pivot table can summarize the data nicely, but you need to give us an example of what you want the data to look like before we can give you a good answer to your question.

Comment: *can sort first column and other columns will change according to first column. but i want to sort all columns together. that mean every column should sort A-Z together.* Does this mean that the result you want is each column to be sorted? ever if some values which were posessed in different columns and in the same row in starting state may occur in different rows in final state? if so it is NOT "together", it is backward "separately".

Comment: @Akina you are correct. i want each column to be sorted

Comment: If so sort each column separately (select column, execute sort, do NOT extend data when asked). In VBA - set proper sorting range (area within single column only) to SetRange property of Workbook.Worksheets(name).Sort object.

Comment: Your edit made the question incomprehensible.  I rolled it back to the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Select the column you want to sort. Then click on "Sort Smallest to Largest".

[image: Data > Sort & Filter > Sort Smallest to Largest]

**2.** Choose "Continue with the current selection".

[image: Continue with the current selection]

You can see, only one column was sorted.
[image: Sorted only one column]

Repeat this for the rest 349 columns :)

---

**In order to do it alltogether in one go:**

1. Open the sheet you want to sort.
2. Open VBA editor using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Insert > Module
4. Paste this code:

```
Sub sort_columns_separately_AZ()
  Dim rngStart As Range
  Dim rngHeaders As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Set rngStart = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
  Set rngHeaders = ActiveSheet.Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlToRight))

  For Each c In rngHeaders
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=c, _
      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
      .SetRange ActiveSheet.Range(c, c.End(xlDown))
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

5. In the code, change `ActiveSheet.Range("A2")` with the cell address where your data table starts, for example `ActiveSheet.Range("B5")` .
6. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

Results:
[image: before sorting and after]

Note: if you have any empty cells in your data, this code will need adjustments in order to work correctly on those columns which have empty cells.

Comment: wow. superb. thank you soooo much. it's amazing.

Comment: If i want to get Z-A. where i should change it.

Comment: Done it by using Sort and filter tool. But can you tell me how i can do it by VB script.

Comment: If you want Z-A (technically it is called *descending*), you would need to change `Order:=xlAscending` to `Order:=xlDescending` .

Comment: It seems it worked out. If so, please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer, marking the question as answered.